# jQuery Removing HTML element with Select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to remove `<div>` element by using `<select>` `option`, but the problem is that my `<option>` and `<div>` are dynamically generated, so I'm not sure how to get those using jQuery since I haven't used it a lot.

This is how the `<div>`looks like:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='item_div' id='uniqueName1'>
    <img src=''>
    <p class='img_title'>'uniqueName1'</p>
  </div>
 <div class='item_div' id='uniqueName2'>
    <img src=''>
    <p class='img_title'>uniqueName2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can see in `<select>` options names such as `uniqueName1` `uniqueName2`. Now lets say I pick `option` with name `uniqueName1`, I would like to remove `<div>` with the `id` `uniqueName1` after I click the button. Basically the parent `id` is the same  as the child `<p>` `text`.

This is how I get `options` for `select`

```
let itemArray = [];
let item = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('img_title')).map(function(x){return x.innerHTML});
    for(let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
        itemArray.push(item[i]);    
    }
let itemOption = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
        itemOption += "<option value='" + itemArray[i] + "'>" + itemArray[i] + '</option>';
    }
$('#selectOpt').append(itemOption);
```

for removing item :

```
$(document).ready('click', '#rmvBtn', function() {
        if($('#selectOpt').val() === /*I'm not sure what goes here for comparison*/) {
            $('.img_div').parent().remove() /*not sure if its correct too*/;
        }
})
```

Comment: Why `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('img_title')).map(function(x){return x.innerHTML});` when there's jQuery?

Comment: And why do you `.push()` every item of `item` into `itemArray`? Why `itemArray` at all?

Comment: It's just the way I used it get the ```p``` text, not saying its the best way

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: `$(document).ready` probably should be `$(document).on("click"...`

Comment: Inside your click handler:  `$("#" + $("#selectOpt").val()).remove()`

Comment: I was playing around so I forgot to change to ```on```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Build your options. This is even easier if you build them from your `.item_div` elements

   ```js
   const divs = $(".item_div[id]")
   const options = divs.map((_, { id }) => $("<option>", {
     value: id,
     text: id
   })).toArray()

   $("#selectOpt").append(options)
   ```

   See https://api.jquery.com/map/ and https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes
2. Remove the selected option on click

   ```js
   $("#rmvBtn").on("click", () => {
     $(`#${$("#selectOpt").val()}`).remove()
   })
   ```

---

Demo...

```js
const divs = $(".item_div[id]")
const options = divs.map((_, { id }) => $("<option>", {
  value: id,
  text: id
})).toArray()

$("#selectOpt").append(options)

$("#rmvBtn").on("click", () => {
  var id = $("#selectOpt").val()
  $(`#${$("#selectOpt").val()}`).remove()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item_div" id="uniqueName1">
    <img src="">
    <p class="img_title">'uniqueName1'</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item_div" id="uniqueName2">
    <img src="">
    <p class="img_title">uniqueName2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<select id="selectOpt"></select>
<button type="button" id="rmvBtn">Remove selected</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. Does your builder for options does not require ```</option>``` at the end?

Comment: No, that's how you get jQuery to create tags... `$("<tagname>", attributes)`. See https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes

Comment: I did try using your builder, but it does not populate the ```select```, i get error for some reason: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined

Comment: @Auri-stack sorry, I had a couple of errors. All fixed now

Comment: Thank you for your magic. But I have same question for you too, since my items in ```container``` are populated by php, is there an extra step I need to do to make removal work?

Comment: @Auri-stack no, PHP runs on the server. The JS runs in your browser and can make any changes to the current page. It won't change what the PHP will generate if you reload the page though

Comment: Well that's what I thought, but for some reason I cant get deletion to work, going to double check if everything is correct again

Answer (score 1):

By linking the `select` `option` value to the ID of the element you want to remove, your removal code becomes a simple:

```
$("#" + $("#selectOpt").val()).remove()
```

Updated snippet:

```js
// build select automatically
$(".img_title").parent().each((i,e)=> $("#selectOpt").append("<option value='" + e.id + "'>" + e.id + "</option>"));

$(document).on('click', '#rmvBtn', function() {

    // remove the related element
    $("#" + $("#selectOpt").val()).remove();
    
    // Also remove the selected option from the select
    $("#selectOpt option:selected").remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='item_div' id='uniqueName1'>
    <p class='img_title'>uniqueName1</p>
  </div>
 <div class='item_div' id='uniqueName2'>
    <p class='img_title'>uniqueName2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<select id="selectOpt"></select>

<button id="rmvBtn">remove</button>
```

Comment: Everything here makes sense, but I'm trying it for myself and it does not change anything.
I populate ```container``` by using PHP, could that be a problem?

Comment: Always check the *rendered* HTML, not just the source (php)

Comment: Stick with how you want to create the `option`s - I just added a quick one-liner to ensure the `select` had matching IDs.  Make sure your remove button Id matches.

Comment: Your quick one-line is  fine. But I'm not really sure what you mean by rendered HTML? Is there an extra step I need to do?

Comment: @Auri-stack Right-click on the page and select _"View page source"_ in your browser

Comment: Well, they are rendered, I thought you meant something different. So I guess this has to do with something else then?